# how to Count the number of non zero pixels of the canny image in my python program

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find the number of non zero pixels of the canny image, *could you help?*

Here is my code:

```
import cv
def doCanny(input, lowThresh, highThresh, aperture):
    if input.nChannels != 1:
            return(0)
    out = cv.CreateImage((input.width, input.height), input.depth, 1)
    cv.Canny(input, out, lowThresh, highThresh, aperture)
    return out
def doPyrDown(input):
    assert(input.width !=0 and input.height !=0)
    out = cv.CreateImage((input.width/2, input.height/2), input.depth, input.nChannels)
    cv.PyrDown(input, out)
    return out

img = cv.LoadImage('mypic.jpg')
img2 = cv.CreateImage((img.width, img.height), img.depth, 1)
cv.CvtColor(img, img2, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
cv.NamedWindow("Example GRAY", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv.ShowImage("Example GRAY", img2)
img3 = doCanny(img2, 10, 100, 3)
img2 = doPyrDown(img3)
cv.ShowImage("Example 2", img2)
cv.WaitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use opencv's function [`countNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) for counting the number of non-zero pixels in the image.

```
img3 = doCanny(img2, 10, 100, 3)
nzCount = cv.CountNonZero(img3);
```

## Update:

In newer versions of OpenCV, the function to count non zeros has been updated as follows:

```
nzCount = cv2.countNonZero(img3)
```

Comment: if i give " print nzCount " will the value be printed?

Answer (score 1):

Try `cv.countNonZero()`, `CountNonZero()` doesn't work for me.