# How to select only non-zero values and copy them to a new Mat file

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an image that has a big portion of black background:
[image]
How can I select only pixels that are not black, and copy them to a new MAT variable.
In matlab this goes something like this: 
1. Create binary mask that covers all black pixels and that shows only gray image.
2. Use code: `newImage = myImage(~mask)`

The reason wanting this is, that I want to calculate Otsu's threshold on the gray part of the image and exclude black pixels from calculation: 
[How to use Otsu Threshold on desired range of a histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432109/how-to-use-otsu-threshold-on-desired-range-of-a-histogram?noredirect=1#comment72009228_42432109)

Comment: Check out [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981238/how-to-count-the-number-of-non-zero-pixels-of-the-canny-image-in-my-python-progr)

Comment: `number = cv2.findNonZero(mask)`